# Is the iPad "page turn" transition included in the SDK?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, transition

Is there a "page turn" transition included in the iPad SDK that I can use? Or is that all coded by hand with core graphics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a little bit late, but I'm currently using an Framework called "leaves" which have different forks which even support zooming or two page view. I've even figured out to make my app slightly faster and run with less memory.
Check it out at GitHub:
https://github.com/brow/leaves

Comment: This is definitely late. 'leaves' is a proof-of-concept and little else.

Answer (score 10):

the code for curl Animation is given below :

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [oldView removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Enjoy....

Comment: The UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp option was introduced in iOS4.0 whereas the iPad, for some indefinable reason, is running in iOS3.2 still. None of the fancy view transition effects work.

Comment: Certainly works fine on ios5 if anyone is still wondering. Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The page turn transition is included in the SDK, but it is a private API.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Is now (since iOS 5.0) included, look at: [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html).

---

Besides Leaves, there's two other libraries out there for this, that are even more realistic:

- [PageCurl](https://github.com/jemmons/PageCurl): Really nice effect, easy to use.
- [Implementing iBooks page curling using a conical deformation algorithm](http://wdnuon.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html): Amazing, but it's just a proof of concept, difficult to expand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's an available function for that. This seems to be near what you're looking for though: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/32624-creating-uibutton-page-turn-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer these links which might help you :

http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=289017982158

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/32624-creating-uibutton-page-turn-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the below link ,

http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2010/02/apples-ibooks-dynamic-page-curl.html

it is  Apple iBook Dynamic page curl application , it will be solution for, what would you

expect  exactly .

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 5.0 the support is included in the public SDK API.

The easiest way to try it is to start a new project with the latest Xcode version (4.3.2 when writing) and choosing **Page based Application**.

The class involved is the `UIPageViewController`.